# onClick open url in same window

Tags: javascript, php, html

Need help with the onClick function for this button

```
<input type="button" class="cta-button" value="<?php the_field('button-text'); ?>" onclick="window.open('<?php the_field('button-link'); ?>')">
```

I need the button to open the url passed from the ACF field in the same window instead of a new blank window, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Does it need to be an input-button?
What about an anchor-link instead? 

    <a class="cta-button" href="<?php the_field('button-link'); ?>"><?php the_field('button-text'); ?></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `windows.location`

```
<input type="button" class="cta-button" value="<?php the_field('button-text'); ?>" onclick="window.location = '<?php the_field('button-link'); ?>'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `window.open` use `window.location.href`

```
<input type="button" class="cta-button" value="<?php the_field('button-text'); ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php the_field('button-link'); ?>'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="window.open('<?php the_field('button-link'); ?>', '_self')"`. Specifying `_self` will open the link in the current window instead of opening a new one.